# Fragment duplicate tab Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

i have fragment which have three tabs in, after i came back to HomeFragment from another activity it's same i have duplicate layout

please inform me if I'm doing something wrong ?

[image]

HomeFragment.class

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup container ,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

            // [Start Tabs]
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_fragment);
            //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences);


            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragmetn_viewpager);

            setupViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs_fragment);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            //[*End Tab ]

            return rootView;
        }


        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment() , "Tab1");
            adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment() , "Tab2");
            adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment() , "Tab3");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

And:

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public TabLayout tabLayout;
    public ViewPager viewPager;

    private static int currentItem = 0;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    public static TabFragment newInstance(int someInt) {
        TabFragment frag = new TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("tab", someInt);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("currentItem", viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    public static TabFragment newInstance() {
        TabFragment frag = new TabFragment();

        return frag;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter=new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        currentItem=getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("tab") : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
         */
            View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**
         *Set an Adapter for the View Pager
         */
        if (adapter==null) adapter=new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem( currentItem);

        /**
         * Now , this is a workaround ,
         * The setupWithViewPager doesn't work without the Runnable .
         * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
         */

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                   }
        });

        return x;

    }

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
          switch (position){
              case 0 : return new Tab1Fragment();
              case 1 : return new Tab2Fragment();
              case 2 : return new Tab3Fragment();
          }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Tab1";
                case 1 :
                    return "Tab2";
                case 2 :
                    return "Tab3";
            }
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't hold static references of Views (and especially not inside a fragment) - there is a good chance to create a memory leak.

Comment: @Doron Yakovlev-Golani Would you have a possible sample where a memory leak could occur?

Comment: For example - you create activity A and hold a static reference to a ViewPager in it. You open activity B instead of Activity A and Activity A is destroyed. However, the static reference is still not cleared (as it is static) and it maintains a reference to the activity. This would cause what is called a "leaked activity" (we all did it before, you just need to make sure you use good practices to avoid it). You can read some more about similar memory leaks in this blog: http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html

Comment: thank you so much its work. but in first app launched i should go to another activity and came back to see tabs

Comment: @Doron Yakovlev-Golani  Thank you. You are sure.

Comment: @Farzad Mohebbi Check if you are using "replace" with transaction fragment instead of "add"

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani should i use this code if not  what's your suggestion for my problem

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the static views, so I think after the changes it is safe to use.

Comment: Maybe you can post your code here, then we could help you.

Comment: @Doron Yakovlev-Golani Thank you. I have seen.

Comment: @Farzad Mohebbi You are wellcome